# Flex Mobile 4.6 App wont create Database on IOS?

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, flex4, flashbuilder4

I have been creating Mobile Application in Flex for over a year now and have done many complicated things, however recently something simple that i am trying to do is not working for a new mobile app I am creating.

I simply want to be able to create a sqlite db on the device so i can read and write data to it, to create the database I have used the code below:

```
sqlConnection = new SQLConnection();
                sqlConnection.open(File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("New.db"));
                var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
                stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
                stmt.text = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cars (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name VARCHAR(90))";
                stmt.execute();
```

Then when I test the App in debug from within Flashbuilder all looks ok for both android and IOS. However when I run the app on the device for some reason the database is not created :-S

This is very odd to me as I am sure I have used the right code as I have used the following code below in another app which is exactly the same as you can see and when i run that app on IOS it creates the database fine :-S :-S

```
sqlConnection = new SQLConnection();
                sqlConnection.open(File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("Bikes.db"));
                var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
                stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
                stmt.text = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS makes (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name INTEGER)";
                stmt.execute();
                stmt.text = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS models (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name INTEGER)";
                stmt.execute();
```

I don't understand why the old app that I have created would work and the new one wouldn't?? Does anyone know if there are any other elements that need to be in place in order to allow me to write this database file to IOS? just to note I have added all permissions to the manifest, i appreciate the help :-)

Comment: can someone please assist with this :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the documentsDirectory is write protected on iOS.

For application specific files, use the `File.applicationStorageDirectory` instead. You have both read and write access to that directory out of the box, no altering of permissions required.